# Grails/GORM where-clause how to set the fetchMode property

Tags: grails, properties, grails-orm, where-clause, fetch

In Grails 2, we all know that a where clause creates a DetachedCriteria. Also, one can set the fetchMode property of a relationship when creating a normal Criteria query. But, if I'm creating a where-clause query, how do I set the fetchMode property of the underlying Criteria?

Does not work:

```
MyDomainClass.where {
  foo == 'bar'
  fetchMode "reference", FetchMode.EAGER
}
```

works, but uses old Criteria style, not where clause:

```
MyDomainClass.withCriteria {
  eq "foo", "bar"
  fetchMode "reference", FetchMode.EAGER
}
```

Please don't tell me to set the fetch mode to eager in the domain class mapping. I know about that, and need to control the eager fetching at the query level. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported yet, so please create a feature request at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS

There is a somewhat hackish workaround though by accessing the Hibernate `Criteria` instance that does the actual querying:

```
MyDomainClass.where {
   foo == 'bar'
}.withPopulatedQuery(null, null) { query ->
   query.@criteria.setFetchMode('reference', FetchMode.EAGER)
   query.list()
}
```